# Checking connection to MySQL (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I'm working on creating my *little-utility* for MySQL, and I need some help.
How I can check connection to MySQL *(by login and password)*, like it was realised in **phpMyAdmin**, without pointing some database at first. Because most of solutions for work with databases need exactly that pointing.
*Thanks in advance)*

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading this wrong, but it sounds like you want to check that you can connect to a database without connecting to that database?

Comment: Actually no) I want to check connection to host, where databases are located...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can connect to the server without specifying the database in the connection url.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"; //pointing to no database.
    String username = "myusername";
    String password = "mypassword";

    System.out.println("Connecting to server...");

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
        System.out.println("Server connected!");
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet resultset = null;

        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            resultset = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW DATABASES;");

            if (stmt.execute("SHOW DATABASES;")) {
                resultset = stmt.getResultSet();
            }

            while (resultset.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultset.getString("Database"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){
            // handle any errors
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            // release resources
            if (resultset != null) {
                try {
                    resultset.close();
                } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { }
                resultset = null;
            }

            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException sqlEx) { }
                stmt = null;
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the server!", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only comment is that if you know the username and password, I'd edit to those details.